# Backdrop Modal and Dropdown Menu Conflict

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker

I have a situation when a user clicks the "Open" button, the Modal backdrop opens and allows a datetimepicker to dropdown. How do I keep it so that when a user "scrolls", the datetimepicker "stays" in its place and not move as the page scrolls? I need to keep `.modal { position:fixed;}` as it is or else the Modal backdrop will not extend the entirety of the page(You might have to view the Code Snippet in full view to see exactly what's going on).

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(function() {
 $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
  timePicker: true,
  startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
  endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
  locale: {
   format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #89f7fe 0%, #66a6ff 60%, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  margin:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: animatetop;
   animation-duration: 0.4s
}

  .daterangepicker select {
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="css/couponsexample.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <span style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; width:100%; padding:0;">
                <button class="buttonTest" id="myBtn">Open</button>
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content" >
          <form id="msform">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <fieldset>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4</h3>
                  <input type="text" name="datetimes" />
        </div>
              </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="couponsjs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date picker has a class ".daterangepicker" , it has a default position of absolute. Replace it with fixed & add !important so that it will not be overridden by the datepicker library.

`.daterangepicker {
  position: fixed !important;
}`

You may need to adjust the top, left accordingly.
Now the data-picker stays in its fixed position & won't move even when the page is scrolled.

Comment: Nice! that worked and put it in the same place. Is there a way to allow the user to show the entirety of the date picker? Is that like a max-height thing?

Comment: How do i see the rest of the date and the time? I cant only see a portion of it when using position:fixed